# Google calendar missing some events

Tags: google-calendar-api

My ICAL PHP script validates OK but certain events are not appearing in Google Calendar.

My **PHP url** is here:

```
http://www.thefishy.eu/calendar.php
```

- Google Calendar shows the first 9 events up to Aug 1.
- Then it misses out 11 events until Sep 15. After that its fine.

This page shows all the events correctly.

http://www.instantcal.com/isc/js/cvu.html

Is this some kind of caching problem with Google because I am pretty sure the ICAL is correct?

**UPDATE:** here is the source of the calendar

This event is an example of one (the first) that does not appear

> VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Kidderminster (away) UID:101
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150808T140000Z DTEND:20150808T160000Z
>   LOCATION:Aggborough Stadium END

**Full source:**

> BEGIN:VCALENDAR METHOD:PUBLISH VERSION:2.0
>   PRODID:-//TheFishy.co.uk//Grimsby Town Fixtures Calendar//EN
>   X-WR-CALNAME:Grimsby Town Fixtures 2015/16 BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Cleethorpes Town (away) UID:631 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20150708T180000Z DTEND:20150708T200000Z LOCATION:Bradley
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Derby County (home) UID:632
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150711T140000Z DTEND:20150711T160000Z
>   LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:North Ferriby
>   United (away) UID:633 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150714T183000Z
>   DTEND:20150714T203000Z LOCATION:Grange Lane END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Gainsbrough Trinity (away) UID:634 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20150718T140000Z DTEND:20150718T160000Z LOCATION:The Northolme
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Huddersfield Town (home) UID:635
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150721T183000Z DTEND:20150721T203000Z
>   LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Brigg
>   Town/Grantham (Lincs Cup) (away) UID:636 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20150722T180000Z DTEND:20150722T200000Z LOCATION:TBA
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Notts County (home) UID:637
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150725T140000Z DTEND:20150725T160000Z
>   LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Peterborough
>   Utd (home) UID:638 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150728T183000Z
>   DTEND:20150728T203000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Boston Utd (home) UID:639 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20150801T140000Z DTEND:20150801T160000Z LOCATION:York Street
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Kidderminster (away) UID:101
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150808T140000Z DTEND:20150808T160000Z
>   LOCATION:Aggborough Stadium END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Barrow
>   (home) UID:102 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150811T184500Z
>   DTEND:20150811T204500Z LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Bromley (home) UID:103 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20150815T140000Z DTEND:20150815T160000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Altrincham (away) UID:104
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150818T184500Z DTEND:20150818T204500Z
>   LOCATION:Moss Lane END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Torquay (home)
>   UID:105 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150822T140000Z
>   DTEND:20150822T160000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Lincoln City (away) UID:106 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20150829T140000Z DTEND:20150829T160000Z LOCATION:Sincil Bank
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Macclesfield (home) UID:107
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150831T140000Z DTEND:20150831T160000Z
>   LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Boreham Wood
>   (away) UID:108 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150905T140000Z
>   DTEND:20150905T160000Z LOCATION:Meadow Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Aldershot (home) UID:109 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20150912T140000Z DTEND:20150912T160000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Chester (away) UID:110
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150915T184500Z DTEND:20150915T204500Z
>   LOCATION:Deva Stadium END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Tranmere (home)
>   UID:111 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150919T140000Z
>   DTEND:20150919T160000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Wrexham (away) UID:112 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20150922T140000Z DTEND:20150922T160000Z LOCATION:Racecourse
>   Ground END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Southport (away) UID:113
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20150926T140000Z DTEND:20150926T160000Z
>   LOCATION:Haig Avenue END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Forest Green
>   (home) UID:114 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20151003T140000Z
>   DTEND:20151003T160000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Gateshead (home) UID:115 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20151006T184500Z DTEND:20151006T204500Z LOCATION:Blundell Park
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Braintree Town (away) UID:116
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20151010T140000Z DTEND:20151010T160000Z
>   LOCATION:Cressing Road END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:FC Halifax
>   (home) UID:117 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20151013T184500Z
>   DTEND:20151013T204500Z LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Torquay (away) UID:118 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20151017T140000Z DTEND:20151017T160000Z LOCATION:Plainmoor
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Cheltenham (home) UID:119
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20151031T150000Z DTEND:20151031T170000Z
>   LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Barrow (away)
>   UID:120 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20151110T194500Z
>   DTEND:20151110T214500Z LOCATION:Holker Street END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Welling (home) UID:121 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20151114T150000Z DTEND:20151114T170000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Eastleigh (away) UID:122
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20151121T150000Z DTEND:20151121T170000Z
>   LOCATION:Ten Acres END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Kidderminster
>   (home) UID:123 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20151128T150000Z
>   DTEND:20151128T170000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Bromley (away) UID:124 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20151205T150000Z DTEND:20151205T170000Z LOCATION:Hayes Lane
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Dover (home) UID:125 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20151219T150000Z DTEND:20151219T170000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Guiseley (away) UID:126
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20151226T150000Z DTEND:20151226T170000Z
>   LOCATION:Nethermoor Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Lincoln City
>   (home) UID:127 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20151228T150000Z
>   DTEND:20151228T170000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Guiseley (home) UID:128 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20160102T150000Z DTEND:20160102T170000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Welling (away) UID:129
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160109T150000Z DTEND:20160109T170000Z
>   LOCATION:Park View Road END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Altrincham
>   (home) UID:130 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160123T150000Z
>   DTEND:20160123T170000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Gateshead (away) UID:131 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20160130T150000Z DTEND:20160130T170000Z LOCATION:International
>   Stadium END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Woking (home) UID:132
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160206T150000Z DTEND:20160206T170000Z
>   LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Boreham Wood
>   (home) UID:133 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160213T150000Z
>   DTEND:20160213T170000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:FC Halifax (away) UID:134 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20160220T150000Z DTEND:20160220T170000Z LOCATION:The Shay
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Southport (home) UID:135
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160227T150000Z DTEND:20160227T170000Z
>   LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Aldershot
>   (away) UID:136 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160301T194500Z
>   DTEND:20160301T214500Z LOCATION:Recreation Ground END:VEVENT
>   BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Forest Green (away) UID:137 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20160305T150000Z DTEND:20160305T170000Z LOCATION:The Lawn
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Braintree Town (home) UID:138
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160312T150000Z DTEND:20160312T170000Z
>   LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Woking (away)
>   UID:139 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160319T150000Z
>   DTEND:20160319T170000Z LOCATION:Kingfield Stadium END:VEVENT
>   BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Wrexham (home) UID:140 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20160326T150000Z DTEND:20160326T170000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Macclesfield (away) UID:141
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160328T184500Z DTEND:20160328T204500Z
>   LOCATION:Moss Rose END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Cheltenham (away)
>   UID:142 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160402T140000Z
>   DTEND:20160402T160000Z LOCATION:Whaddon Road END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Eastleigh (home) UID:143 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20160409T140000Z DTEND:20160409T160000Z LOCATION:Blundell Park
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Dover (away) UID:144 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20160416T140000Z DTEND:20160416T160000Z LOCATION:Crabble
>   END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Chester (home) UID:145
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160423T140000Z DTEND:20160423T160000Z
>   LOCATION:Blundell Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT SUMMARY:Tranmere (away)
>   UID:146 STATUS:CONFIRMED DTSTART:20160430T140000Z
>   DTEND:20160430T160000Z LOCATION:Prenton Park END:VEVENT BEGIN:VEVENT
>   SUMMARY:Wembley (away) UID:211 STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   DTSTART:20160522T140000Z DTEND:20160522T160000Z LOCATION: END:VEVENT
>   END:VCALENDAR

Comment: Please describe your use case clearly. Are you trying to integrate Ical events to google calendar? when you are trying to list events, some events were missed out?

Comment: If you add my URL to google Calendar and look at august you will see hardly anything there. July and all other months are fine.

Comment: Out of interest this took several days to go away and then resolved itself #weird